# Get left table data completely even when there is no reference in right joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

Database used: SQL Server

I have three tables A,B,C.

TABLE A:

```
------------------
| ID    |  Name  |
------------------
| 1     |   X    |
------------------
| 2     |   Y    |
------------------
```

TABLE B:

```
----------------------
|  ID   |  Date      | 
----------------------
|  1    | 2019-11-06 |
----------------------
|  2    | 2019-11-05 |
----------------------
```

TABLE C:

```
----------------------------------
| ID    | B.ID  | A.ID  | Amount |
----------------------------------
| 1     |  1    |  1    | 500    |
----------------------------------
| 2     |  2    |  2    | 1000   |
----------------------------------
```

The result I would like to get is all entries of table A.Name with their amount in table C.amount where table B.Date = 2019-11-06. The result set should include all A.name entries even it have no reference in Table C.

Required result is:

```
-----------------------
| A.Name   | C.Amount |
-----------------------
| X        |   500    |
-----------------------
| Y        |   NULL   |
-----------------------
```

Code I tried with :

```
SELECT A.Name,C.Amount
FROM A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN C ON C.A_ID=A.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON B.ID = C.B_ID ON 
WHERE B.Date='2019-11-06'
```

The result I obtained with above code is :

```
------------------
| Name  | Amount |
------------------
| X     |  500   |
------------------
```

There is no Y in the result, its because there is no entry for Y on that particular date. I just want to show Y and amount as null or zero.

[SQL Fiddle with my query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ab030/6/0)

Please help me with this.

Comment: Learn about outer joins. PS This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's is no relationship between your `A and B`, so we need to group `B and C` using a `subquery` to filter with `date` before doing the left join.

```
SELECT A.Name, t1.Amount
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT C.A_ID, C.Amount FROM C 
    INNER JOIN B ON B.ID = C.B_ID 
    WHERE B.Date='2019-11-06') t1
     ON t1.A_ID=A.ID
```

see [dbfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ab030/19/0)

Comment: I tried your answer and it's working fine. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

[Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ab030/26)

```
SELECT A.Name,C.Amount
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID AND B.Date = '2019-11-06'
LEFT JOIN C ON B.ID = C.ID
```

Output is-

```
Name    Amount
X       500
Y       (null)
```

Comment: I tried your answer but the problem is when more data is present in a single date, this is not working.